# How can I create a RULE that INSERTS values of TABLE1 to TABLE2 when a SELECT query is made on TABLE1

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have realized I can't create triggers for SELECT hence banking on RULES.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE log_select AS 
ON SELECT TO usertable 
DO ALSO INSERT INTO selectLOG(prim_key,val)
VALUES(prim_key,val);
```

The above example does not work with the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "prim_key" does not exist
LINE 4: VALUES(prim_key,val)
               ^
HINT:  There is a column named "prim_key" in table "old", but 
it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Basically, I want to insert rows into table2 when user makes SELECT on table1.

Comment: MySQL, Oracle or PostgreSQL? I don’t think you’re using all three to run the same query but you’ve tagged them all.

Comment: Thanks, changed it now. I am using PostgreSql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Laurenz pointed out, this is not possible with a rule.

But did you consider a function that gives access to that table, rather then direct access to the table itself?

You can create a function that runs the query, stores the result and returns it. Then only grant execute privilege on the function and revoke any direct access to that table.

Something like:

```
create function get_usertable(p_key integer)
  returns setof usertable
as
$$
  with result as (
     select *
     from usertable
     where id = p_key
  ), log_query as (
     insert into selectlog (prim_key, val)
     select *
     from result
  )
  select *
  from result;
$$
language sql;
```

The major drawback of this solution is, that you have to provide parameter for any condition that might be necessary (the parameter `p_key` is just an example). If the options for the `WHERE` clause are limited, then this might be an alternative. If you need more complex where conditions, you could do that with dynamic SQL (and a PL/pgSQL function instead of a SQL function), but that also gets ugly quick.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/rules-views.html#RULES-SELECT) says:

> Currently, there can be only one action in an `ON SELECT` rule, and it must be an unconditional `SELECT` action that is `INSTEAD`. This restriction was required to make rules safe enough to open them for ordinary users, and it restricts `ON SELECT` rules to act like views.

So you won't be able to do what you want.

The options you have are either to use the log file or to write C code that hooks into the query executor.

If you want to use logging, set `log_statement = all` or `log_min_duration_statement = 0`, then all statements, including `SELECT`s, will be logged.

As a hook in the source code, you could use `ExecutorEnd_hook` from `include/executor/executor.h`. That will be called when the executor winds up, and `queryDesc->sourceText` will point to the statement being processed. Read [`auto_explain`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=contrib/auto_explain/auto_explain.c;hb=HEAD) for an example how this hook can be used.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Can you elaborate on "use the log file" please? my logs are set to debug2 level and I don't expect any SELECT response to be logged there. And I have not dug through Postgres code base, so not sure where exactly I need to put the hooks. The goal is to log SELECT (conditional or not) queries on a particular table.

Comment: I have extended the answer to explain that.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer! however, I have log_statement=all and og_min_duration_statement = 0 the SELECT operations are logged but the response received from the select query won't be. Which is what I am trying to achieve. As for the hooks let me have a look at it, thanks for the reference.

Comment: Capturing the result is a totally different pair of shoes and will probably be more difficult. Why don't you write a proxy that sits between client and server? The protocol [is well documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol.html). That would be much simpler.

Comment: had the same thought but I am keen on staying in the database layer and not have any application/proxy do the logging. I am benchmarking a particular use case.